# Are there commands for entrances, exits, and exeunts, while employing the dramatist package?

Tags: dramatist, screenplay

So, I've been working with the `dramatist` package for typesetting a script of a play for a school project in LaTeX. Does the `dramatist` package include commands for the entrances, exits, and exeunts for characters?

So this is one scene of the play:

```
\scene[--Delhi]

\StageDir{
 \begin{center} Indira Gandhi International Airport\\\poi, \lem
    \end{center}
}

\begin{drama}

\lemspeaks
So, let me get this straight, M. Poirot -- Rebecca has murdered Desmond, and is aware of the Prince's stay in Delhi, and the latter might be murdered by Rebecca because she wants the real ruby?\\
\poispeaks
Exactly. It seems as if both Desmond and Rebecca were competing to steal the ruby again, but Rebecca had murdered Desmond out of anger because of his betrayal. Oh goodness, it's the paparazzi!\\\\
\patspeaks
It's M. Poirot! He's arrived! Goodness, M. Poirot, did you solve the case? He must have! HURRAY!\\
\poispeaks
Now wait just a moment!\\
\patspeaks
It's his words, folks! 'Wait just a moment!'\\
\lemspeaks
Oh dear, I think we should go.\\\\
\divspeaks
STOP! WAIT! \direct{to the jostling mob} OUT! out -- all of you! \direct{to M. Poirot} M. Poirot, let me take you to the crime scene. Come here...
```

Now, just after 'because of his betrayal', and 'Oh dear, I think we should go', I've added linebreaks and want to add a command with which I can easily show

```
\itshape{Enter} PATIL \itshape{and other news reporters} %% or simply \pat as I have set. If you there is a way to integrate that into the function, that would be great.
```

and

```
\itshape{Enter} DIVAKAR %% or \div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such commands defined in the package, but you can add them yourself.

In the MWE below I have defined three commands `\enter`, `\exit` and `\exeunt`. The `\enter` command has an optional first argument to add *and X* to the output. Each command starts a paragraph, then contains some spacing commands based on the indentation and line spacing settings of the `dramatist` package, and then the template text (enter, exit, exeunt) and the argument. The previous speaker continues after the command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\newcommand{\enter}[2][]{
\par\vspace{\speechskip}\hspace{1.15\speaksindent}
\textit{Enter} #2 \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\textit{and #1}\fi\par\vspace{\speechskip}
}

\newcommand{\exit}[1]{
\par\vspace{\speechskip}\hspace{1.15\speaksindent}
\textit{Exit} #1\par\vspace{\speechskip}
}

\newcommand{\exeunt}[1]{
\par\vspace{\speechskip}\hspace{1.15\speaksindent}
\textit{Exeunt} #1\par\vspace{\speechskip}
}

\begin{document}
\Character{M. Poirot}{poi}
\Character{Patil}{pat}
\Character{Divakar}{div}
\Character{Lunar Excursion Module}{lem}

\scene[--Delhi]

\StageDir{
 \begin{center} Indira Gandhi International Airport\\\poi, \lem
    \end{center}
}

\begin{drama}

\lemspeaks
So, let me get this straight, M. Poirot -- Rebecca has murdered Desmond, and is aware of the Prince's stay in Delhi, and the latter might be murdered by Rebecca because she wants the real ruby?\\
\poispeaks
Exactly. It seems as if both Desmond and Rebecca were competing to steal the ruby again, but Rebecca had murdered Desmond out of anger because of his betrayal. \enter[other news reporters]{\pat} Oh goodness, it's the paparazzi!\\
\patspeaks
It's M. Poirot! He's arrived! Goodness, M. Poirot, did you solve the case? He must have! HURRAY!\\
\poispeaks
Now wait just a moment!\\
\patspeaks
It's his words, folks! 'Wait just a moment!'\\
\lemspeaks
Oh dear, I think we should go.\enter{\div}\exit{\lem}
\divspeaks
STOP! WAIT! \direct{to the jostling mob} OUT! out -- all of you! \direct{to \poi} M. Poirot, let me take you to the crime scene. Come here...
\exeunt{reporters}
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]